# Collapsing 2 divs instead of 1 Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that call a div depending if a cart is full or empty

```
<a class="basket-btn btnCollapse basket-desk" type="button" title="VIEW SHOPPING BAG" onclick="minicart.noactive(this);" id="bag-customer">
    <span id="header-cart-item-count" 
    data-cart-count="<?php echo $numCartItems ? $numCartItems : 0; ?>">
        [<?php echo $numCartItems ? $numCartItems : 0; ?>]
    </span>
</a>
```

the div's are below:

```
<div class="row row-links collapse" id="rowSBag" >
            <?php $this->renderPartial('//partial/shop_bag_header'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row row-links collapse" id="rowSBagEmpty">
            <?php $this->renderPartial('//partial/empty_shop_bag_header'); ?>
</div>
```

The problem is that if a clicked in the button when the bag is empty show the correct div `rowSBagEmpty` but if I clicked in the button (bag empty) then I add a product, my script show me both div's `rowSBagEmpty` and `rowSBag` and not the last one.

My script is below:

```
var minicart = {
    init: function() {
        var count = $('#header-cart-item-count').data('cart-count');
        minicart.show(count);
    },
    show: function(products) {
        if (products > 0) {
            $('#header-cart-item-count').parent().attr('data-target', '#rowSBag');
        } else {
            $('#header-cart-item-count').parent().attr('data-target', '#rowSBagEmpty');
        }
    },
    noactive: function(button) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(button).removeClass('active');
        }, 1);

    },
    expand: function() {
        $.get('/cart')
            .done(function(page) {
                var content = $(page).find('#rowSBag').html();
                $('#rowSBag').html(content);
                var parent = $('#header-cart-item-count').parent();
                $('#rowSBagEmpty').remove();
                $(parent).trigger('click');
                $('#rowSBag .info').css('display','none');
                $('#AddToCart').attr('disabled', false).removeClass('btnSecondary').html('Agregar al carrito');
                $('#addedtobag_ok').fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#rowSBagEmpty').remove();
                    $('#rowSBag').collapse('toggle');
                }, 2000);
            });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    minicart.init();
});
```

I was tried removing the div `BagEmpty` but if i do this, the div `rowSBag` just only show but not hide with the `timeout`

Answer (score 0):

You are just showing div, not hiding any. So I think if you add 'hide' function as well it will work.

```
        var minicart = {
        init: function() {
            var count = $('#header-cart-item-count').data('cart-count');
            minicart.show(count);
        },
        hide: function(products) {
            if (products > 0) {
                $('#header-cart-item-count').parent().attr('data-target', '#rowSBagEmpty');
            } else {            
                $('#header-cart-item-count').parent().attr('data-target', '#rowSBag');
            }
        },    
        show: function(products) {
            if (products > 0) {
                $('#header-cart-item-count').parent().attr('data-target', '#rowSBag');
            } else {
                $('#header-cart-item-count').parent().attr('data-target', '#rowSBagEmpty');
            }
        },
        noactive: function(button) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(button).removeClass('active');
            }, 1);

        },
        expand: function() {
            $.get('/cart')
                .done(function(page) {
                    var content = $(page).find('#rowSBag').html();
                    $('#rowSBag').html(content);
                    var parent = $('#header-cart-item-count').parent();
                    $('#rowSBagEmpty').remove();
                    $(parent).trigger('click');
                    $('#rowSBag .info').css('display','none');
                    $('#AddToCart').attr('disabled', false).removeClass('btnSecondary').html('Agregar al carrito');
                    $('#addedtobag_ok').fadeIn();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#rowSBagEmpty').remove();
                        $('#rowSBag').collapse('toggle');
                    }, 2000);
                });
        }
    };
```